# Google Direction JSON to POJO (Jackson)

Tags: java, json, jackson, google-directions-api

Problem: Trying to convert JSON from http request (Google Directions) to POJO (simply my own classes). I have by now "root" class "GoogleGeoCodeResponse" (GGCR further in text, containing some top level fields like status, routes, etc.) and inside it there're some others (routes contain this class and that, etc.). I'm getting

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "geocoded_waypoints" (class Main.GoogleGeoCodeResponse.GoogleGeoCodeResponse), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "status", "geocodedWaypoints", "routes"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1717824; line: 2, column: 28] (through reference chain: Main.GoogleGeoCodeResponse.GoogleGeoCodeResponse["geocoded_waypoints"])
```

when trying to convert using `ggcr = mapper.readValue(json, GoogleGeoCodeResponse.class);` (json is String) even with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` at GGCR class.

By now I'm completely stuck and any ideas would be appreciated. Getters and setters are defined for GGCR only, fields are private in GGCR and public in other classes, gets/sets - public.

EDIT:
Main class:

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String json="";
    String origin = "Manhattan+New+York+USA";
    String destination = "Newark+New+YorkUSA";
    String mode="bicycling";
    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin="+origin+"&destination="+destination+"&mode="+mode);
        URLConnection yc = url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            json+=inputLine+"\n";
        }
        in.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }

    GoogleGeoCodeResponse ggcr=null;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        ggcr = mapper.readValue(json, GoogleGeoCodeResponse.class);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
    if (ggcr!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Status: " + ggcr.getStatus());
    }
}
```

or here http://pastebin.com/pEeqn4f2

GGCR:

```
public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse {

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
private String status;
private GeocodedWaypoint[] geocodedWaypoints;
private Route[] routes;
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public GeocodedWaypoint[] getGeocodedWaypoints() {
    return geocodedWaypoints;
}

public void setGeocodedWaypoints(GeocodedWaypoint[] geocodedWaypoints) {
    this.geocodedWaypoints = geocodedWaypoints;
}

public Route[] getRoutes() {
    return routes;
}

public void setRoutes(Route[] routes) {
    this.routes = routes;
}
```

or here http://pastebin.com/Fs5DYPSY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)` annotation in the top of your class. It's a class level annotation.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class GoogleGeoCodeResponse {

private String status;
private GeocodedWaypoint[] geocodedWaypoints;
private Route[] routes;

...
```

In your case, it seems that Jackson is trying to map a JSON field to a non-existent property. You can fix it in two different ways:

Using a annotattion

```
@JsonProperty("geocoded_waypoints")
private GeocodedWaypoint[] geocodedWaypoints;
```

Or configuring your ObjectMapper:

```
objectMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
    PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

I would go with mapper configuration since the API you are using uses underscores by default for field names. In that way you can avoid having to annotate every class member with `@JsonProperty`.

Comment: If I understood correctly from quick test, property is not going all the way down, so if I need to ignore some fields in deeper-level class I need to define it again, correct?

Comment: (My assumption seems to be correct by further testing). The problem is, geocodedWaypoints is not being assigned (is null), does it mean (in simple words) that Jackson lib. considers there's no place in my model for geocodedWaypoints from JSON and therefore ignores it setting to null?

Comment: It seems that Jackson is trying to find a property in your object that do not exists. You should annotate your `geocodeWaypoints` with `@JsonProperty("geocode_waypoints")` or configure your `ObjectMapper` to convert underscores to camel case. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Well, that seems to resolve the problem, so basically you want to follow the following rule: either name fields the same way, either make annotation, or define those rules in mapper? And probably it's a good idea also to mention fields to ignore? Or simply say ignore unknown should be sufficient? Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes, you have those three ways, but by Java conventions you can't use underscores in your class members (or anywhere really). I update my question with my opinion in which one to use.

Comment: Ignore field by field or ignore unknown depends exclusively on your requirements. If you ignore field by field it's easier to find unmapped properties, but if the API suddenly change the response (eg. add a new field), your application will break.